# C# - Failed to close an old form after a new form is shown

Tags: c#, forms, show

I'm creating a login function. After validating the password, the main form will be called.
Here is the partial code:

Login.cs

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Interaction with Database
    Main.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

As I expect only the Login form will be closed and the Main form will remain unchanged.

However both of them are closed after the last command is executed.

How can I fix this problem please ?

Comment: Looks like you are closing the main executing thread maybe.

Comment: In your program.cs which form is in Application.Run(new what??);

Comment: I'd like to thanks you all first as I'm surprised that I can get such many replies from you. I agree the alternative mentioned by Servy is good and applicable in this case (Considering the Login form as a dialog of the Main form), but seems it didn't solve the problem radically: If now I got 3 forms named A, B and C; In A we have two buttons, clicking one of them will jump to either B or C. Obviously we can't predict the selection of user in this case, ultimately I want to know how to close the old form independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program.cs put in `Application.Run(main);`

Then in `main.load` event open your login form using show dialog.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Main());
}
```

and on main

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Login p = new Login();
    DialogResult dr = p.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //...
    }
    else
        Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: You'd also need to hide the main form when it's first created so it's not in the background.

Comment: You wouldn't want to show information that required credentials before the user has provided said credentials, otherwise what's the point of asking for credentials?

Comment: Also, you can just close the main form rather than calling app.Exit if the dialog hasn't confirmed a successful login.

Comment: You may have blank main with controls. I aggree with the secobd post.

Comment: What would be the point in showing a blank form?  It would be at best confusing to the user.  There's no reason for it to be shown, so it should be hidden.  It's two lines of code to hide it before showing the password dialog and then to show it again afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for remaking my post. I was in a hurry. Thx

Comment: In the future you should make a point of at least formatting your code before posting the answer.  It greatly detracts from its readability otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you close your main Form, application terminates. Instead of closing, you can hide your main Form with :

```
this.Hide();
```

Comment: You don't want to have the login form hidden for the entirety of your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // hide main form
    this.Hide();

    // show other form
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();

    // close application
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: You don't want to have the login form hidden for the entirety of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Program.cs file you will see a command similar to this:

```
    Application.Run(new PasswordForm());
```

The form specified in this command is what ties the program into existence, when this form closes the STA Thread continues execution and then finishes, closing the whole application.

To fix this, create an instance of you password form and do all that in the Program.cs file before calling Application.Run on the main UI form.